# PHP generate several PDFs - fast way

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I need to generate several PDF invites (template is the same, only changes a few variables from PDF to another) and I'm currently using html2pdf. It all works OK but the time consuming is maybe a little too much (100 invites generated in 2min30s).

Here's some of the code inside the cycle:

```
        $file = $number.'.pdf';
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L',array(148,69),'fr', false, 'ISO-8859-1', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content, '');
    $html2pdf->Output('Tickets/'.$file, 'F');
```

Is there a better way to generate lots of PDF files? The size of each PDF file is about 28kb

Comment: Upgrade your server's hardware.

Comment: Converting HTML to PDF isn't really easy, computationally. You have to parse the HTML file, convert the parsed representation into one that can be used to layout a PDF, and then create a PDF and add all these elements. If you can skip the first steps, the process should be much faster.

Comment: yeah, I'm afraid it is really a slow process :( Will it improve if I try to implement threading in PHP ? (I don't know how, but maybe is possible xD )